# C * operator meaning in array assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

What does this line mean? I havn't done C in a few years. Does it perform the operation in parens then make the int result a pointer??

```
b[0] = *(start + pos++);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently `start` is a pointer (or an array, which will decay to a pointer here anyway), which means that the result of the expression in `()` is a pointer, not an `int`. The `*` simply dereferences that pointer.

The whole thing is equivalent to plain `b[0] = start[pos++]`, but for some reason some people prefer to use the obfuscated form as in your post.

Comment: Ok, I'm upvoting you but I take offense at the "obfuscated" comment. If you were to keep only two of the three redundant constructs: `p[e]`, `*p`, and `p+e`, the clearest programs would be obtained by keeping the latter two (but I may be partial, working on a C static analyzer whose first transformation is to make all `p[e]` in the program into `*(p+e)` in order to limit the number of constructs to study).

Comment: Well, firstly, I'm not sure what you mean by "three redundant constructs", since they are not equivalent. Secondly, as for `p[e]` vs `*(p + e)`, I'd say that the latter has its applications in some contexts, but in my opinion the `[]` form is much more readable in most cases.

Comment: I prefer e[p]. Especially when used like
i < 10 ? i["0123456789"] : i-10["abcdef"].

Comment: Oops, I think I forgot parenthesis around i-10.

Comment: Aside from the out-of-bounds access, it is valid even without the parenthesis. Depends on what you wanted to achieve :)

Comment: No, I mean `i - 10["abcdef"]` is syntactically valid, but `10["abcdef"]` is trying to access the 10-th element of `"abcdef"` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndreyT "Redundant" means that if you keep all other C constructs, and two of the three I wrote, you can encode the third one. You can get `*p` by `p[0]`, **OR** `p+e` by `&(p[e])`, **OR** p[e] by *(p + e).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming start is pointer and pos is an integer, it can be easily rewritten to:

```
b[0] = start[pos++];
```

Hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 3):

For this to make sense, either `start` or `pos` must be a pointer; most likely, it will be `start`. The code can then be written as

```
b[0] = start[pos];
pos = pos + 1;
```

Actually, the code is equivalent even if `pos` were the pointer because of C's somewhat funny semantics of array subscription.

Answer (score 2):

The operator '*' returns the value at the location pointed to by the pointer or expression following the operator.

Some examples:

```
value = *pointer;
value = *(pointer);     // Exactly the same as the first statement.
value = *(pointer + 0); // Take contents of pointer and add zero then dereference.
value = *(pointer + 1); // Deference the first location after the location in pointer.
```

Sometimes, especially in embedded systems, this is more readable than using the array notation.  Example:  `status = *(UART + STATUS_REGISTER_OFFSET);`

Comment: +1 for the example of why this syntax would be useful (assuming the use of appropriately named variables)

Answer (score 1):

Note the equivalence of these expressions. First, assume the following declarations establish the types in play:

```
T* const base;
size_t const pos;
```

Now, an object of type `T` located in memory at position

```
base + sizeof(T) * pos
```

can be accessed in several ways:

```
base[pos]                            // Interpret base as an array.
*(base + pos)                        // Pointer arithmetic strides by sizeof(T)
*(T*)((char*)base + sizeof(T) * pos) // Compute stride manually
```

Comment: Your last line is not correct, it should read:`*(T *)((char*)base + sizeof(T) * pos)` else you will only get the first `char` of your element.

Comment: You're right. I'm more used to writing this in C++, using `reinterpret_cast`, and I blew it here. I corrected the third example after writing a sample program to confirm that the compiler was dissatisfied with my first pass and satisfied with the revision.